# find command giving different outputs with/without -print

Tags: linux, unix, find

```
find src/ -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.cpp" -print
find src/ -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.cpp"
```

The intended behavior is to find all C++ files in a directory and all its subdirectories. As I understood it, the -print command was the default. However, these two commands give me significantly different results. If I redirect them to a file (`printed` and `notprinted`, respectively):

```
$ wc -l printed notprinted
1813 printed
1979 notprinted
```

Diffing each sorted file doesn't help me much. There's no clear pattern for what's excluded from `printed`.

What's going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is the precedence. If no action is given, then it prints, but if you specify an action then it does what you asked for. Your example with `-print` only prints `.cpp` files. You probably want:

```
find src/ \( -name "*.cc" -o -name "*.cpp" \) -print
```

You can have multiple conditions with different actions.

Comment: Ah, that's why. Figured it had to be something simple. I'll accept it as soon as it lets me.